# Rejected push despite branch is not checked out

Tags: git

I want to push my git repo to my origin and it fails with the following error message:

```
! [rejected]            develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
...
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@remote_git_repo/project/foo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

`foo` and `bar` are checked out in worktrees, and `master` is the current one. I think I didn't check out `develop` at any time.

```
$ git branch
  develop
* master
+ foo
+ bar
```

Does anyone know how I can push my repo, **without merging**? A `git pull` succeeded. Any "local" state of "develop" could be discarded.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? What `git push` command are you running? What have you set `push.default` to, if anything?

Comment: Git v2.6.0, `push.default` is not set in my config. I use `git push --all` or `git push -u origin --all`

Comment: Ah. OK: then either don't use `--all` (which says to push all branches), or delete local branch `develop` if you really don't care about it. (The error itself is somewhat harmless in this case, but it occurs because you explicitly told your Git to ask *their* Git to set *their* `develop` based on your `develop`.)

Comment: I would need to push all branches. But I am wondering why `develop` is marked because I can't see it's checked out anywhere

Comment: It's irrelevant whether a local branch name is *checked out*. What matters is whether it exists, and if so, whether you then choose it as one of the series of requests that you send with a `git push` operation. `--all` means *look at all of my local branches; send each name as part of this push request*.

Comment: Thank you so much @torekt. I incorrectly assumed that the missing * means I don't even have the branch locally on my machine. So a simple `git branch -D develop` worked. I would accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: The answer of @Torek below will receive the corresponding bounty in 23h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

The problem in this case was due to misunderstanding the `--all` option for `git push`, which means *push all branches that I have at all* (vs *push all checked-out branches*).  You did not really want the local `develop` name in the first place, and (**this part is important**) did not mind discarding any commits that were only reachable from the name `develop`, so deleting the name `develop` solved your immediate problem:

```
git branch -D develop     # this is a force-delete, skipping safety checks
```

There are some useful caveats, notes, and historical items worth mentioning here.

## Long

The question text above shows that you have a pretty modern Git, with `git worktree` as an available command.  In particular, this `git branch` listing:

> ```
> $ git branch
>   develop
> * master
> + foo
> + bar
> ```

indicates the existence of four (local) branch names: `develop`, `master`, `foo`, and `bar`.<sup>1</sup>  The asterisk `*` indicates that branch `master` is the current branch name in the main work-tree.  The two plus signs `+` indicate that branches `foo` and `bar` are each checked out by name in each of two added work-trees.  The blank in front of `develop` shows that while local branch `develop` exists, it is not checked out anywhere.

Versions of Git predating Git 2.5 lack `git worktree add` and can have at most one branch checked-out at any time.  However, any number of (local) branch names can exist.

---

<sup>1</sup>`foo` and `bar` are clearly replacements as `git branch` defaults to sorting alphabetically, and these are in the wrong order.

---

#### Side note: all branches are local

While Git has *remotes* like `origin` and *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`, all *local* branch names are local, and in fact, the word "local" in front of "branch name" is redundant.

The way to think about this is this:

- Git is a *distributed* version control system (DVCS), as opposed to a *centralized* VCS like Subversion.  In a Centralized VCS (CVCS), there is a master server somewhere.  It holds *the* repository.  You don't have *the* repository on your own computer.  You just extract a bunch of files *from* the CVCS.  You work with those files, then you put those files back into *the* (central) VCS.

  With a DVCS, you actually get some or all of the repository: a *duplicate* or *clone*.  The default with Git, and the way to think about it, is that you get a full clone: a copy of *every* version that the other copy-of-every-version also has.

  In any distributed system, the distributions can either talk to each other all the time, or synchronize at specific dedicated meet-ups.  Git (like many other DVCSes) chooses the latter because it has to: the networks and computers across which we share Git repositories are not always up, or may not give all permissions to everyone, or whatever.  So we need dedicated re-synchronizations.

  The synchronization events for Git occur using `git fetch` and `git push`, which are not quite symmetric.  We'll see more about this in a moment.
- Being a repository, Git stores many versions of files.  Different VCSes use different methods to do this.  In Git's case, the unit of storage here is the *commit*.  That is, Git does not store *files*, exactly.  Git stores *commits*, and then each *commit* contains some set of files.  The packaging unit is the commit: you either have all of a commit, or none of it.
- This means that when you connect two Gits to each other to get them to *share*, the level at which they share stuff is the *commit*.  To that end, every commit has its own unique name.  The name of a commit is its hash ID.  When one Git has a commit for another Git, the sender offers the commit to the receiver, by its name—its hash ID.  The receiver looks in its database: *Do I have this hash ID?  If so, I have this commit: tell the sender no thanks, I already have it.  If not, I don't: tell the sender yes please, send that one.*

  Note that these hash IDs are universal.  That is, every Git uses the *same* hash ID for the same commit.  That's why it is OK to check by hash ID.
- In Git, each commit lists its immediate previous or *parent* commit(s) by their hash IDs.  These allow Git to form backwards-looking chains of commits:

  ```
  ... <-F <-G <-H ...
  ```

  where some hash ID `H` gives Git a way to fish that commit out of its database.  The commit itself then contains the hash ID of earlier commit `G`, which lets Git fish the commit out of its database, which finds the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.
- In Git, *names*—not just branch names, though we'll just consider branch names here—just hold the hash ID of *one* of these commits.  That's sufficient, because as long as a branch name holds the hash ID of the branch's *last* commit, Git can find all the previous ones, using the chains:

  ```
  ...--F--G--H   <-- master
        \
         I--J   <-- develop
  ```

  Here, `H` stands for the *last* commit in `master`, while `J` stands for the *last* commit in `develop`.
- **Every Git repository has its own set of names** because each Git repository can *add* commits to a branch!  When you `git checkout` a branch by name, you are asking your Git to:

  - take all the files *from* that commit (in deep-freeze storage) and put them into a work area;
  - let you work on the files; and
  - let you make a *new* commit from the updated files

  and when you do this, you end up with a new commit added to the branch.  The new commit automatically points back to what *was* the *last* commit, a moment ago:

  ```
  ...--F--G--H--K   <-- master
        \
         I--J   <-- develop
  ```

  for instance, if you've just added a new commit to your `master`.

  Hence *your* Git's branch names are completely separate from *their* Git's branch names, regardless of who they may be.  *Your* branch names remember *your* last commits.  Theirs remember theirs.  If those are the same, that's fine.  If not, well, that's where fetch and/or push tend to come into the picture.

So all branch names are always local.  They find the last commits, from which Git finds earlier commits.

When you get a bunch of commits from another Git—let's call that other Git `origin`, as we usually do—that *other* Git had *its* branch names.  That's how they found the commits they gave to your Git.  Your Git now, cleverly, remembers their branch names, using your *remote-tracking names*.  Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`.  Their `develop` becomes your `origin/develop`.

This means you don't need *any* branch names to remember these commits.  Your remote-tracking names are sufficient:

```
...--F--G--H--K   <-- origin/master
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

But you can't make *new* commits using a remote-tracking name.  You can only make new commits on a branch name.<sup>2</sup>  So you now need to *create* some branch name(s), if you want to make new commits.

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, you *can* make new commits when not on a branch, in Git's *detached HEAD* mode.  But this doesn't make them on a remote-tracking name, it just makes them in detached HEAD mode.  As soon as you switch back to a branch name, the commits you made this way become hard to find, and eventually Git just removes them as unused.  So you don't normally want to work this way at all.  Detached HEAD mode is mainly for Git's own internal use.

---

#### A work-tree can only be on one branch

Git's commits are frozen forever: read-only for all time.  It's literally impossible to change any part of any commit, even for Git itself.<sup>3</sup>  They are also in a special, compressed—sometimes highly compressed—Git-only form.  So in order to get any actual work done, Git has to take the files out of a commit and put them into normal everyday form.

The everyday form, where your files are just files instead of special weird Git-only things, is what you find in your work-tree, or—since the advent of `git worktree add`—any work-tree, including added ones.  To *fill in* a work-tree, you pick a commit, usually by picking a branch name, and switch to that commit:

```
git switch <name>
```

or:

```
git checkout <name>
```

Git removes, if necessary, all the old files associated with the previous checkout, and switches to the files associated with the *last* commit on the named branch.  You're now "on" that branch, in that `git status` will say `on branch master` or whatever, and `git branch` will mark that branch name with an asterisk `*` or plus-sign `+` as appropriate.

The act of switching *to* a branch name can result in the *creation* of that branch name.  This is Git just attempting to be smart and helpful.  If you say:

```
git checkout develop
```

and you don't *have* a `develop`, but you *do* have a remote-tracking name `origin/develop`, your Git will say to itself: *aha, I don't have that, but I do have something that could **become** that* and will now *create* your own branch name `develop`, pointing to the same commit as your `origin/develop`:

```
...--F--G--H--K   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

The `HEAD` here indicates that, at least in this work-tree, that's the branch name you're now using.

When you first clone a repository, Git automatically does a `git checkout master`, or `git checkout` (or `git switch`) of some other name you choose somehow.  That automatically creates the first branch name in a new clone, and is why I have `master` pointing to commit `K` above.

For various important internal reasons, each work-tree is constrained to be on a *different* branch name, or to use a detached HEAD (either is OK so you can have as many added work-trees on detached HEADs as you like).  All work-trees *share* the set of available branch names, and creating a new work-tree can create a new name the same way switching to a branch in your main work-tree created `develop` here.

The added work-trees share these repository-wide branch names *because* they all share the same repository.  A standard repository comes with:

- A big database of commits and other Git objects, named by hash IDs.
- A smaller database of names—branch names, remote-tracking names, and so on—that give you the hash ID of *one* commit.  For a branch name, this is the *last* commit in the branch.  For a remote-tracking name, this is your Git's memory of some other Git's branch name, the last time your Git talked with that Git (see below).
- One index-and-work-tree pair.

Using `git worktree add`, you add more index-and-work-tree pairs to the repository.  This allows you to have more than one commit and/or branch checked out at one time.  We have not mentioned the index (and won't go into any detail here), but it really is paired with the work-tree.  So is the notion of `HEAD`: each added work-tree has *its own* `HEAD`.

Every time you `cd` into or out of any one given work-tree, you change the index-and-work-tree pair and switch to another `HEAD`.  There are other special *reference names*, like `ORIG_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD`, that are also per-work-tree.  But the *branch* names are shared.

---

<sup>3</sup>The real reason for this read-only state has to do with those hash IDs, though we won't cover these details here.

---

#### Transferring commits and getting/setting names with fetch and push

As I mentioned above, `git fetch` and `git push` allow you to connect your Git to another Git.  This lets you obtain commits from them (`fetch`) or send commits to them (`push`).  The details can get very complicated, but from a high level view, it's really pretty simple.

These two are not symmetric!

When you `git fetch`, your Git calls up the other Git.  The other Git lists its branch names (and other names), and the hash IDs for each of the *last* commits in these branches (and any other stored hash IDs).  Your Git then checks, for each <name, hash-ID> pair:

- Do I want to update my copy (`origin/master` etc)?
- If so, do I have that commit?

The other Git will offer the tip commits of all the branches by their hash IDs, and your Git will either say *yes please* or *no thanks, already have that one* as appropriate.  If your Git asks for a commit, their Git is obliged to say *... and its parent(s) is/are these other hash IDs* and your Git can ask for those, and their parents, and so on.

Once your Git is done asking for commits, they package them up—`counting` and `compressing` and so on—and send them over.  Your Git now has the commits *and* the updated branch names, and can update your remote-tracking names.

The default action for `git fetch origin` is to get *all* of its branches and update *all* of your remote-tracking names.  Since those aren't for *you* to update, it's fine to just update them all now.  You cannot be "on" a remote-tracking name: an attempt to `git checkout origin/master` just gets you into Git's *detached HEAD* mode.  So if `origin/master` *moves* to point to some other commit, that doesn't affect your checkout.

The fetch operation is a one-way transfer: from them, to you.  You don't *give* them any commits, though you do tell them that you don't *want* certain commits, implying that you already have them.  Then, having fetched all their branch names, your Git updates all your remote-tracking names.  There is no need for an `--all` option: `--all` is automatic.

The push operation is as close as you get to the opposite, but it's not quite opposite.  Your Git calls up their Git.  You don't normally need a list from them of their branch names.<sup>4</sup>  You just start offering them commits.  For instance, if you run:

```
git push origin develop
```

your Git will offer whichever commit is the *last* commit in *your* `develop`, by hash ID.  They check to see: *do I have that commit?*  If not, they ask your Git to send it, and your Git offers its parent, and they check that, and so on.  Eventually you and they find some commit they already have, and you don't need to send that one, nor anything that comes before it: they already have *all* of those.

Suppose you run:

```
git push origin develop foo bar
```

Assuming `develop`, `foo`, and `bar` all list different hash IDs, your Git will now offer theirs *three* commits initially.  They'll have your Git add parent commits until they reach commits that they already have.

In any case, your Git now packages up these commits (`counting`, `compressing`, etc) and sends over the package.  Then—this is where push is so very different from fetch—your Git sends over some polite requests:

- Please, if it's OK, set *your* branch name `develop` to _____ (hash ID).
- Please, if it's OK, set *your* branch name `foo` to _____ (hash ID).
- Please, if it's OK, set *your* branch name `bar` to _____ (hash ID).

So it's crucial which *names* you use on your side, because you're going to ask them to set the *same names* on *their* side.

Push and fetch are therefore not symmetric in two different ways:

- The obvious one is the direction of transfer: fetch means *get stuff from them* and push means *send stuff to them*.
- The less-obvious one is that fetch is "safe": it updates your *remote-tracking* names.  Push is not as safe: it asks them to update their *branch* names directly.  If they have added commits since the last time your Git talked with their Git, they may have a new *last* commit.  It won't be OK for them to change their name, because if they change which commit is the *last* one, maybe some commits will "fall off" the end.

To see why that's the case, consider this situation.  You start with a fresh clone and you get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

You add a new commit `I` to *your* `master`, but while you're doing that, they add a new commit `J` to *their* `master`.  If you run `git fetch` now, you'll pick up their `J` and adjust your own `origin/master` to remember it, and you will now have:

```
          I   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- origin/master
```

You can certainly send them commit `I`.  But then you tell them: *Now make your `master` point to `I`, OK?*  If they do that, *they* won't be able to *find* commit `J` any more.  It will "fall off the end" because `I` points back to `H`, not to `J`; nothing will point to `J` any more.

They will answer your polite request with: *No, it's not OK!  Rejected: not a fast forward.*

---

<sup>4</sup>If you've asked for a `matching` style push, your Git *does* need the list of their branch names.

---

#### Historical matters

In Git versions before Git 2.0, `git push` defaulted to pushing *matching* branches.  That is, it would list your branches, and list theirs, and see which names matched up.  Then it would politely ask their Git to set *all* of those names based on all of your names (after sending any commits needed, of course).

Since Git 2.0, `git push` defaults to a mode named `simple`.  This means it defaults to pushing only the *current* branch, and even then, requires that your Git and their Git use the *same name*, and has some other requirements as well to avoid common Git-newbie traps.

To allow you to easily send *all* your branch names, `git push` has the `--all` option.  This means *all branches* (not *all refs*—which would include tags—but specifically just the branches).  It does not matter how many are checked out.  In Git before 2.5, only one could *be* checked out anyway.

Meanwhile, `git fetch` has always defaulted to fetching *all* their branch names to your own remote-tracking names.<sup>5</sup>  So there's no need for an `--all` option to mean *all branches*.  But `git fetch` *does* have an `--all` option: it means *all remotes*.  This only matters if you have more than one remote.  You can add extra remotes using `git remote add`, but after an initial clone, most people have only one remote, and never add any more, so mostly, `git fetch --all` does not do anything useful.

---

<sup>5</sup>Technically, this is controlled by the setting of `remote.name.fetch`, where *`name`* is the name of the remote.  But the default for that is "all branch names".  There was an early period, long before Git 1.7, when the details were changing around for this as well, but they stabilized pretty quickly and nobody seems to use a Git that predates 1.7.

---

#### Conclusion

If you want to use the `--all` option, you'll want to carefully control the set of branches that you actually have.  You only need a branch name at all if you plan to use it to make *new* commits over time, but remember, your branch names are the primary way your Git *finds* your commits.  If you intend to delete one, make sure it's OK to delete it now: that you've sent your commits to some other clone of the same Git repository, if you want to keep them.